# How to create new file with iphone .xib file?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface

In Xcode, when I create a new file, it gives me the option to include an iPad sized .xib file. How can I get the .xib for iPhone size?

Comment: By the way, All programmers i know advice never to use xib files and do all the ui programmatically. Xibs make a mess in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple

Right click your iPad xib, go for reveal in Finder-> save that file in other system path->Rename by removing -iPad from your file name.

Now, drag that xib into your project, resize your xib to 320*460 if Portrait orientation.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck that option "Targeted for iPad" while creating new file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you created your project you selected "Devices: iPad". Change that to Universal, and after that you can create iPad and iPhone xib files.